# excel sum variables of same values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following table:
[image: Table]

It shows an SKU and then the duration of production for the SKU, then a new SKU and the duration.

What you can see is SKU 1 and then SKU 2 which is new, and then SKU 3-10 which are the same as SKU 1. When this occurs I would like to sum them. The result will look something like this:
[image: Result]

I would like to do this without VBA and with formulas. There are never more than 10 SKU's and therefore 10 durations.

Comment: Can you change this into a 2-columns vertical list? Then you could use a =SUMIF() with a list of SKUs

Comment: That does not work because SKU 1 has code 0235 adn SKU 3 till 10 also have 0235. Then it adds it together, but they are not produced consequently after eachother because SKU 2 is in between. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to Sum the Values for the Last 8 SKU you can use:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(E2:T2,E2)=8,SUMPRODUCT(--(E2:S2=E2)*F2:T2),"")
```

Where E2 is the SKU that is repeated in SKU3-10
E2:T2 being the values of SKU3---Process10

Comment: This wont work if the order changes, correct? For example if there is another split between SKU 3 -10. SKU 3-5 are the same, SKU 6 is different and SKU 7-10 are the same as SKU 2.

Comment: You have to show all combinations and how you want the result

Comment: The combinations change. There could 10 completely different options or 2 the same, then 3 the samen then 1 different, etc....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to SUM several values that have a key (SKU) in common you can use the SUMIF command:

[image: sumif]

1. Put your data in 2-columns, with the first column being the SKU and the 2nd the value.
2. Make a list of the SKUs which sum you care about.
3. Write the command:

> =SUMIF(keysList,valueToFind,valuesList)

Like this:

> =SUMIF($A$3:$A$9,D3,$B$3:$B$9)

And this command will search in the list all the appearances of SKU and sum its value.

Comment: Hi and thanks, issue is that I can put it in this order, but in the case of your example I would like the output as: SKU 1 = value, SKU 2= value, SKU 3= value, SKU 1 (sum) = Value, SKU 2 = value and SKU 1= value. This SKU structure is a formula as well and changes as we move through a production plan.